# Angular 16 routes in live app won't fully work

Tags: angular

I built a website with Angular 16, bought a domain name from porkbun.com and bought a hosting plan with orangehost.com.  I got everything loaded into my c-panel and running live.  When visiting the site on my computers everything works however when I go to the site on my iphone 12, clicking some of the links freezes the page in both Chrome and Safari and on Android everything works perfectly fine.

Also if I right click a link and open in a new tab, I get my hosting provider's 404 page, I can't type a particular path in the title bar and go directly to that page.

My project uses all standalone components and I'm lazy loading my routes, when I register my routes I'm using the `withInMemoryScrolling()` method with the `scrollPositionRestoration` option set to `true` to make the browser scroll back to the top of the page when the user clicks a link otherwise the new page will load at the same scroll position they were on the previous page.  Other than that I'm using the `[routerLink]`on my links to change paths, I don't know could be causing this.  Does anybody know what the problem is?

***UPDATE***

I created a `.htaccess` file with the following content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

that solves the problem with getting a 404 error on reloads and opening a link in a new tab, however some pages still won't load on my iphone.